# Database Relationship Transaction and Reference Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms, foreign-key-relationship, database-normalization

Hi I have some questions regarding what i'll do with foreign data if deleted

i have: a transaction table and it has foreign keys to user and branch

so if a delete a user thats being referenced by the transaction table the transaction record

will also be deleted what will I do?? can you guys please give me some advice?? thanks

my tables are: Transaction, Branch and User

1 Branch can have Many Transactions 
 1 User can have many Transactions

Transaction 1-------* Branch
Transaction 1-------* User

so if i delete either a user or branch the transaction record referencing to it will also be deleted.. if i dont cascade the delete it will just be an orphan id in the transaction table with no user or branch to reference to. so what shall I do with this? please help..

Comment: write full table structure.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have a foreign key relationship where the action is set to ON DELETE CASCADE. If you don't want the delete to occur in the future, you need to change the foreign key action to ON DELETE NO ACTION.

If you are asking how to get the records back which have already been deleted, you will have to restore them from a backup.

Comment: what if i just flag the record from the user or the branch table as deleted.. i will just add another column with a bit data type.. would that be ok?

Comment: Yes, you can. Then, instead of deleting records physically, you would update the "flag" column as being logically deleted. If you do this, you probably will not be able to use the built in foreign key constraints to maintain referential integrity. You will need to use triggers.